# Create a function that returns a new dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function that takes in a dictionary as an input and returns a new dictionary. In the new dictionary I would like to use the same keys as in the old one, but I've got new values.

This is my old dictionary:

```
animals = {'tiger': ['claws', 'sharp teeth', 'four legs', 'stripes'],
           'elephant': ['trunk', 'four legs', 'big ears', 'gray skin'],
           'human': ['two legs', 'funny looking ears', 'a sense of humor']
           }
```

Then I'm creating a function that takes in the old dictionary and I want it to keep the keys but change values (the new values should pass through a function called bandit. It looks something like this.

```
def myfunction(animals):
    new_dictionary = {}

    for key in animals.keys():
        new_dictionary = {key: []}


        for value in animals[key]:
            bandit_animals = bandit_language(value)
            new_dictionary = {key: bandit_animals}

    return new_dictionary


print(myfunction(animals))
```

The function only prints the last key and the last value and I want it to print a whole dictionary.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

You're initialising a blank dictionary again at every pass through the loop.

This should work:

```
def myfunction(animals):
    new_dictionary = {}

    for key in animals.keys():
        new_dictionary[key] = []

        for value in animals[key]:
            bandit_animals = bandit_language(value)
            new_dictionary[key].append(bandit_animals)

    return new_dictionary


print(myfunction(animals))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome! Can mark as solved (green check) if it's closed :)

Answer (score 0):

A more compact way of doing this by using `items()`:

```
animals = {'tiger': ['claws', 'sharp teeth', 'four legs', 'stripes'],
           'elephant': ['trunk', 'four legs', 'big ears', 'gray skin'],
           'human': ['two legs', 'funny looking ears', 'a sense of humor']
           }

# some dummy function
def bandit_language(val):
    return 'Ho ho ho'


def myfunction(animals):
    return {key: [bandit_language(val) for val in lst] for key, lst in animals.items()}

print(myfunction(animals)
```

This produces:

```
{'human': ['Ho ho ho', 'Ho ho ho', 'Ho ho ho'], 'tiger': ['Ho ho ho', 'Ho ho ho', 'Ho ho ho', 'Ho ho ho'], 'elephant': ['Ho ho ho', 'Ho ho ho', 'Ho ho ho', 'Ho ho ho']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the whole thing in a single line.

```
print({k: bandit_language(v) for k, v in animals.items()})
```

For demo, if I substitute `bandit_language` function with `len`.

```
print({k: len(v) for k, v in animals.items()})
Out: {'elephant': 4, 'human': 3, 'tiger': 4}
```